# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un lista de datos por números de código?

Tags: c++, array, lista, ordenamiento

quisiera que me ayuden de como puedo ordenar una lista de datos por códigos de menor a mayor como:

00001       beto

00002       luis

00003       alejandro

Solo pude ordenar los códigos pero los datos solamente se quedan estáticos así:

00001       jose

00002       alejandro

00003       luis

Aquí el código que avancé:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  

string C[10]={"00004","00003","00002","00001"}, aux;
string N[10]={"jose","alejandro","luis","beto"};

int main() {
    int n=10;   
    int i,j,orde;
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)            
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++) 
        {
            if(C[i]>C[j])
            {
                aux = C[i];  
                C[i] = C[j];
                C[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<""<<C[i]<<;
        cout<<""<<N[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente ya tienes el problema resuelto, tomando en cuenta que los indices de ambos arreglos coinciden lo unico que necesitas es hacer el cambio en ambos arreglos una vez entra al `if` funcional:

```cpp
if( C[i] > C[j] )
{
    aux = C[i]; 
    C[i] = C[j];
    C[j] = aux;

    aux = N[i]; 
    N[i] = N[j];
    N[j] = aux;
}
```

```
00001 beto
00002 luis
00003 alejandro
00004 jose
```